# Append a column stack with json file inputs

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a json file

```
 {  "teams":{
    "0":"Liverpool",
    "1":"Liverpool",
    "2":"Arsenal",
    "3":"City",
    "4":"Watford",
    "5":"Liverpool",
    "6":"Chelsea"
 }
}
```

Code:

```
df = pd.read_csv("clubs.csv")
clubs_df= pd.read_json('domain.json')

clubs =pd.DataFrame.from_dict(clubs_df)  

df = df.stack()
df = df.append(clubs)
df = df.value_counts()
df = df.reset_index()
print(df)
```

If I try to add the values to my stack I get the following error: `TypeError: to_append should be a Series or list/tuple of Series, got DataFrame`

Comment: `df = df.stack()` : You should get an error because you are calling `df.stack()` and df has not been defined yet

Comment: I worded it wrong. Made it readable

Comment: Try with `df = df.append(clubs.stack())`

Comment: try `concat` `pd.concat([df,json_df],1)`